# Can't Fit Model in Python Process?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I can't get my keras model to train within a multiprocessing Process. I have a queue of data that is being written to on the main thread, so I would like the model to simultaneously train itself. However, it just hangs on the line where the call to model.fit() is made. The model is a keras multi gpu model.

I have tried to not make the process a daemon, with no change in results.

This works fine:

```py
def reader_proc(queue, model):
    while (True):
        if (queue.empty()):
            time.sleep(10)
            continue
        d = queue.get()
        x = d[0]
        y = d[1]
        print("training")
        time.sleep(1)
        print(y[0])
        print("done training")
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

This does not:

```py
def reader_proc(queue, model):
    while (True):
        if (queue.empty()):
            time.sleep(10)
            continue
        d = queue.get()
        x = d[0]
        y = d[1]
        print("training")
        model.fit(x=x, y=[y.T[0], y.T[1]], epochs=1, batch_size=32, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback, checkpoint],shuffle=True)
        print("done training")
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

The process is being started like so:

```py
reader_p = Process(target=reader_proc, args=(pqueue, parallel_model))
reader_p.daemon = True
reader_p.start()
```

Calling train on the data outside the process works fine as well:

```py
d = pqueue.get()
x = d[0]
y = d[1]
parallel_model.fit(x=x, y=[y.T[0], y.T[1]], epochs=1, batch_size=32, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback, checkpoint],shuffle=True)
```

When the call to model.fit() is added, the thread prints ("training") but never prints the "done training." The example with sleep works as expected.

Comment: What do you hope to gain by training in another process? Depending how big the training data is, there could be a significant overhead moving all this data to a separate process. And when the model is trained, you don't do anything with it; the trained model would be lost when the `Process`  exits.

Comment: @RolandSmith I'm currently processing the training data on the main process into a multiprocessing Queue. I would save the model after each run and reload it to save progress. The model is only being fed small batches at a time while the other process adds to the queue. In short, I am trying to preprocess the training data into a queue which my model receives, and fill the queue as the model trains.

Comment: Ok, but your trained model will be lost as soon as `reader_proc` finishes... Are you by any chance running this in an interactive Python session like IPython? If so, try running it in a script. Because it seems that `multiprocessing` and IPython don't always get along.

Comment: @RolandSmith before it exits it should save its weights via the modelcheckpoint. I could then reload them on a new call. I am running it in a Jupyter Notebook. My calls to the Pool() and everything else seem to work, but I will try running it on a script nonetheless then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) (see the note at the end of the linked section), `multiprocessing.Pool` does not work in IPython (which is an "interactive interpreter"), especially on ms-windows.